# Getting an image through an API in WCF

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I am just practicing sending data over API in WCF and when I try to send an image I am getting 200 status but I am not getting Image and some weird data. Can someone help me to solve the problem.

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
              RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
              ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
              BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
             UriTemplate = "getphoto")]
    Stream GetImage();

public Stream GetImage()
    {
        FileStream ds = File.OpenRead("D:/pic.jpg");
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingRequest.ContentType = "image/jpg";
        return ds;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried saving the weird data as an image?

Comment: No I have no idea of how to do that @mahlatse

Comment: first instead of stream, save the mage as a byte array ( streams have issues with being closed, etc

Comment: Ok let me try and edit the post with updated code @mahlatse

Answer (score 0):

Here is my two cents on how you can do it,

Instead of send a stream back, send a byte array( streams have a lot of issue especially with seeking data, being unseekable,etc)

You can try

```
public byte[] GetByteArrayFromImage(System.Drawing.Image image)//your image location
{
   using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
   {
      imageIn.Save(ms,imageIn.RawFormat);
      return  ms.ToArray();
   }
}
```

return the Image array, and when you consume the data, you can either check if the image is valid or not, and then also just convert it back to an image

**Added Code to Return back image**

---

If this is called from an ASPNET website, there are a few ways to show the image

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
{
    return Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

The above will return the image that is from the bytes, then in your backend, you will have an ActionResult( not sure if this fits with Angular as I havent used it before) that will return the image

Then you can forgo the top code and just go

```
return new FileContentResult(byteArray, "image/jpeg");
```

and return a FileResult instead, this will make your IMG src tag to be

```
<img id="someImage" src='@Url.Action("getsomeimage", "somecontrollername", new {id ="if you have a need for some parameters, add here"})' />
```

If instead you just want to base64 encode the image, you can use

```
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
        return base64String;
```

the image as set that as your SRC in your image, you will need to create almost the same method as above in an actionResult method and return a string now

The thirds, which is a bit more complex but will give you greater Flexibility, would be to create a TagHelper that will render the img tag given some info

Check https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/853835/TagHelpers on some examples of how to use them.

Comment: Where should I add my image URL? In the place of image?

Comment: What do you hope to achieve at the end? do you just want to send the image through WCF and display it on the client side?

Comment: Ya u r rite. I just need an image to display in my Angular App

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect a few things you can try.

Comment: Ok I ll check it out but where should I add my image url

Comment: I have shown you in the updated answer, in the SRC of the image, use either the base64 encoded string or a controller action that returns an Image(either FileResult or write the image directly to the response stream)

Comment: Let's assume we need an image from D:/pic.jpg and display it in my API call so can u just explain me where will u insert that D:/pic.jpg in backend code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189858/discussion-between-mahlatse-and-gvs-akhil).

Answer (score 0):

You could directly use browser to see your image.
I have wrote similar to your yours and could successfully show the image.
Below is my code.

```
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "getImage")]
  Stream GetImage();

  public Stream GetImage()
    {

        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "image/jpg";
        FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/boatbig.png"));
        return  fs ;
    }
```

My web.config.

```
<endpointBehaviors>
  <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
<service name="Service.Rest.RestService">
 <endpoint address="" contract="ServiceInterface.IRestService" binding="webHttpBinding"  behaviorConfiguration="web" ></endpoint> </service>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
 </system.serviceModel>
```

When I input http://localhost:62193/RestService.svc/getImage in my browser, the image shows
[image]

Comment: My code is working I havent updated Yesterday. My mistake is using OutgoingRequest instead of OutgoingResponse

Answer (score 0):

I got solution and the mistake is using OutgoingRequest instead of OutgoingResponse

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
              RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
              ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
              BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
             UriTemplate = "getphoto")]
    Stream GetImage();

public Stream GetImage()
    {
        FileStream ds = File.OpenRead("D:/pic.jpg");
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "image/jpg";
        return ds;
    }
```